# Какую СУБД лучше использовать?

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты!

Пишу приложение на Delphi, меня интересует: какую СУБД лучше использовать. Пока реализовал всё на InterBase 6.5, одна столкнулся с проблемой: больше 5 обращений к базе невозможно.

Скажите, какие методы есть для того, чтобы избежать это? Знает кто-нибудь: на firebird 2.5 сколько обращений к базе возможно?

Заранее благодарю всех участников переписки.

Comment: Почему не MySQL? Он бесплатный, к нему полно всяких разных бесплатных инструментов для администрирования, просмотра и редактирования. А вообще какие задачи собираетесь решать?

Comment: Никогда на нем не работал и не представляю как подключатся к нему из delphi, однако, если с ним работать будет удобно - то безусловно буду обучаться работать на нем.

Для всех версий Interbase, firebird, yaffil есть программа IbExpert, позволяющая в удобном интерфейсе совершать любые операции, потому пока выбрал именно эти БД.

Comment: 1. постановщик задач, где все задачи будут фиксироваться в БД для отчетности в конце дня, недели, месяца..
2. подключение к IP телефонии для дополнительной фиксации в БД звонков и формирования личных карточек клиентов.
3. подключение к корпоративной почте для фиксации в БД входящих на почту заявок.

вообще список задач велик, там ещё будет учитываться приход/уход сотрудников на рабочие места для премирования в случае переработки, и лишения премий в случае пргулов и опазданий, а так же многое другое...

Comment: а почему вы выбрали старую версию interbase?  
у вас лицензия? или пользуетесь пираткой? 
Если лицензия, то:  
1. покупка дополнительных подключений стоит необоснованно дорого.  
2. можно было бы купить современную версию  
Если пиратка, то почему не поставили какую-нибудь 2009 SMP. Там с кряком ставится неограниченное (в пределах разумного) количество подключений. И интерфейс субд там намного удобнее, чем в 6.5.

Comment: Благодарю, рассмотрю этот вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте firebird.
Согласно FAQ http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq292/ "There is no limit in the Firebird server".
На том сайте на очень много хороших вопросов есть хорошие ответы.

Comment: Замечательно! Большое Вам спасибо!
Но я немного в замешательстве: Firebird - платное или бесплатное СУБД? Читал статью, в которой написано, что бесплатное, а при скачке требуют покупки.

Comment: Где вы выдели, что платное? Firebird - Open Source. Я скачиваю всегда с официального сайта www.firebirdsql.org по ссылке http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/

Comment: Благодарю, выбор сделан:)

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, плюс :)

Comment: Эмм.. я не опытный пользователь данного форума.
Расскажете как - обязательно поставлю:)

Comment: вы уже поставили, спасибо